# VBA to find if a particular word is in a document

Tags: vba

When opening a word document I want to be able to check if a particular word exists in the document. If it does then I want to open a userform. Basically, I have a template letter with "lastname" in place of the recipient's last name in the salutation. When I open the document I want a userform to pop up automatically so I can enter the person's last name in a text box and have the find and replace function run when I click "done" on the userform. If I have already replaced "lastname" with the person's last name then I don't want the userform to pop up. I know how to accomplish everything except for checking to see if "lastname" exists. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Don't have "lastname", have a [bookmark](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-bookmarks-f68d781f-0150-4583-a90e-a4009d99c2a0), and display a form if [the bookmark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834559.aspx) is empty.

Answer (score 1):

in "ThisDocument" code pane place this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim lastNameRng As Range

    Set lastNameRng = GetLastname(ActiveDocument, "lastname") '<--| set 'lastNameRng' range to the one in the active document containing "lastname"
    If lastNameRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if active document doesn't contain "lastname"

    With UserForm2 '<--| change "UserForm2" to your actual userform name
        With .TextBox1 '<--| change "TextBox1" to your actual TextBox name
            .Value = "lastname" '<--| default value
            .SetFocus '<--| make textbox the active control
            .SelStart = 0 '<--| set the textbox selected text start from the beginning of the textbox text
            .SelLength = Len(.Text) '<--| set the textbox selected text length as the textbox text one
        End With
        .Show '<--| show the userform and let the user input its text
        lastNameRng.Text = .TextBox1.Value '<--| change "lastname" to the validated user input in TextBox1 (change "TextBox1" to your actual TextBox name)
    End With
    Unload UserForm2
End Sub


Private Function GetLastname(doc As Document, strng As String) As Range
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content '<--| set 'myRange' to passd dcoument entire content
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=strng, MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True '<--| set 'myRange' to the one containing passed string in the passed document
    If myRange.Find.Found = True Then Set GetLastname = myRange '<--| if 'myRange' has been actually set the return it
End Function
```

in the userform code pane place the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() '<--| change "CommandButton1" to your actual "Done" button name
    If Not ValidateInput(Me.TextBox1) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if invalid input in TextBox1 (change "TextBox1" to your actual textbox name)
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Function ValidateInput(tb As MSForms.TextBox) As Boolean
    With tb '<--| reference passed textbox
        If Trim(.Value) = "" Then '<--| if its content is empty...
            MsgBox "You must enter a last name !", vbExclamation + vbInformation '<--| inform the user
            .SetFocus '<--| make textbox the active control
            .Value = "lastname" '<--| set the "default" textbox text
            .SelStart = 0 '<--| set the textbox selected text start from the beginning of the textbox text
            .SelLength = Len(.Text) '<--| set the textbox selected text length as the textbox text one
        Else
            ValidateInput = True
        End If
    End With
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then '<--| don't let the user close the userform by clicking the white cross at its top left
        MsgBox "Click the 'Done' button to close the form"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Works perfectly!